# How to sort an unordered list inside an anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following DOM structure (unordered list), that I would like to sort on the `a href` tag name using jQuery.

Structure is as follows:

```
<div id="refmenu">
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="....">Google</a></li>
<li><a href="....">Apple</a></li>
<li><a href="....">IBM</a></li>
<li><a href="....">Yahoo!</a></li>
<li><a href="....">Hotmail</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Based on the above, would like to be able to run this through a jQuery function that will sort the unordered list names alphabetically, obviously also keeping the `a href` link together with the anchor tag names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [TinySort](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort) plugin a look at, it sorts child nodes by contents or attributes: [Example](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/10/18/jquery-sorting-divs-by-date/)

**Edit-**

```
$("div#refmenu>ul#platsys>li").tsort("a.title");
```

Also there is no reason for the extra filtering before the **id selector**, selecting by **tag name** does **not speed up** the *performance* when selecting by id. Also your id name for your **ul** is not platsys, so I don't know where you got that from it should be **ul#list>li**, but to shorten all that extra unneeded code I would have

```
$("#refmenu>#list>li").tsort("a.title");
```

actually from your html I think that would be the same as:

```
$("#list>li").tsort("a.title");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not having much luck with trying to get TinySort going based on my above structure. I have tried the following setup:

$("div#refmenu>ul#platsys>li").tsort("a[title]",{orderby:"title"});

as I have added the title attribute within my a hre tag.

Also, unsure where I would call this, i.e is it inside the document.ready() or just within a normal javascript function?

Comment: it would be withing the domcoment.ready(dom) so it would happen as soon as it can

Comment: Thanks again but are you able to check my actual syntax as it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @tonsils- the content between the tags is not the title, but you could add the title attribute to the anchor tag with the same name if you want to sort that way. I think if you update your anchor tag as suggested.. Try updated code

Comment: Thanks all for your help - manage to get it going. Was calling the incorrect div and I also had my unordered list incorrectly structured. FYI, used the following syntax: $("#refmenu li").tsort("a",{attr:"title"});

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = $("#list"),
    listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(list.find("li"));
listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = $("a", a).text(), b = $("a", b).text();
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
});
listItems.forEach(function(val) {
    list.append($(val).remove());
});
```

If you want to sort on a different criteria than the anchor text, replace `text()` by whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [List.js](http://listjs.com/) which will extend your list features to extremes as

1. it's lightweight [only 3K script]
2. easy to implement in your existing HTML table using class
3. searchable, sortable and filterable

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-list">
    <ul class="list">
       <li>
           <h3 class="name">Luke</h3>
       </li>
       <li>
           <h3 class="name">John</h3>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
};
var myList = new List('my-list', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely all your href's here are going to start with http:// or www?  How will sorting that help?

Would an ordered list not do the job?

Comment: I think he wants to sort on the text of the a, not the actual a link

Comment: This is correct. I just added mock up data inside the href values, it's the actual names I want to sort on, i,e Google, Apple, etc.